# Where to put Entity Framework Data Model in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, design-patterns

Lets consider default ASP.NET MVC application folder structure, so it's looks like this:

```
-App_data
-Content
-Controllers
    HomeController.cs
-Models
    AccountModels.cs
-Scripts
-Views
```

My question is: Where is the best place to put Entity Framework Data Model (EDMX) file? Is it Models folder? Yes - we know that good solution is to introduce new Project and reference it to MVC application, but lets forget about this now.

Comment: **WHY** do you want to exclude the proper solution up front - of putting all of this stuff into a separate assembly?? It's the best and cleanest approach - **use it!**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a small project, it should be part of the Model.  For a larger product, the repository and the associated model could be in a separate assembly.

Answer (score 8):

Well this is debatable, but i'd vote +1 for the **Models** folder.

The only other candidate would be **App_Data**, but this is generally for file-based databases (SQL Server CE .MDF, for example) and files you don't want served by IIS.

As the EDMX is an *abstraction* of the database, it should go into the **Models** folder.

If the project gets bigger, you should definetely move your EF Model into another project. To future-proof yourself from this, make your Controllers access the EDMX via Repository/Interfaces, so when you move the DAL over to another project, all you'll have to do is add the reference and add in the using statements.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the EF-model (aka physical model) always in its own assembly or in a "core" assembly outside of main MVC application. The same applies for your business-logic / domain-logic / domain-services / etc. Separate the non-web stuff from the MVC-Web-Application.

This will help you re-use the core part of your app. For example when you need to expose it as a service, a command-line tool, migration-tool, etc.

Because storing this in its own assembly is so easy and takes you a few minutes I highly recommend doing this for each and every tiny app too.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you should create

1. a separate project for domain objects, datacontracts etc. etc...
   Like MyProject.Infrastructure including many folders like
   DataContracts, Model, Exceptions etc.
2. a separate project for DataAccess wich contains the DBContexts and the Repositories, this way you can easily manage migrations later on

Comment: Are two separate projects really necessary? Why not add domain classes and data access classes in one project. If you will have many different backend data stores possibly some non-relational then separate projects for domain classes and data access makes sense.